# ActionScript 3.0 Type Was Not Found Or Was Not A Compile-Time Constant

Tags: actionscript-3

I just started programming a game and I when I ran my code it said

1064:Type Was Not Found Or Was Not A Compile-Time Constant:Event

1064:Type Was Not Found Or Was Not A Compile-Time Constant:Mouse Event

Here is the code:

```
package{
    public class Script_1 {
        public static const STATE_INIT:int = 10
        public static const STATE_PLAY:int = 20
        public static const STATE_GAME_OVER:int = 30
        public var gameState:int = 0
        public function gameLoop(e:Event):void{
            switch(gameState) {
                case STATE_INIT:
                    initGame();
                    break;
                case STATE_PLAY:
                    playGame();
                    break;
                case STATE_GAME_OVER:
                    gameOver();
                    break;
            }
        }
        public function Game(){
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
            gameState = STATE_INIT;
        }
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClickEvent);
        public function initGame():void{
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClickEvent);
            clicks = 0
            gameState = STATE_PLAY;
        }
        public function playGame(){
            if (clicks >= 10){
                gameState = STATE_GAME_OVER;
            }
        }
        public function onMouseClickEvent(e:MouseEvent):void{
            clicks++;
            trace("mouse click number:" + clicks);
        }
        public function gameOver():void{
            stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClickEvent);
            gameState = STATE_INIT;
            trace("game over");
        }
    }
}
```

This is in a file called Script_1.as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import those classes with the [`import`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#import) statement. This statement is required for each class that is missing and belongs above the class definition:

```
package 
{
    // Imports.
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Script_1
    {
        // ..
    }
}
```

Also, some misc things I noticed:

1. You're using `addEventListener()` but `Script_1` does not extend `EventDispatcher` or at least implement `IEventDispatcher`. Based on the events you're trying to listen for, `Sprite` seems most suitable.
2. It looks like your class should either be `Game` or your constructor function `Game()` should be `Script_1()`.